# Git claims that branch is the same as master on local folder

Tags: git

I have a folder of a web crawler which today I started managing it with `git`. Immediately after running `git init` I branched using

```
git checkout -b "change_scrapper"
```

I did my changes there, committed them, and then wanted to merge them with the master. When I run

```
 git merge master
```

git claims that it is `Already up-to-date`. I read in some comments that I should `revert` but I'm not sure on which branch, or if this is applicable to local or remote management. My log graph doesn't show the branch at all (pasted below)

1. What's going on here? Why does git ignore my commits?
2. How to fix this?

   ```
   * commit be9ccb6fa5284e85869c06e7d875f098efcda909
   | Author: Yotam <yotama9@gmail.com>
   | Date:   Sat Oct 17 23:20:33 2015 +0300
   | 
   |     Trying to remove swap files
   |  
   * commit 9b029421582a132718aad121110e46b6c599c292
   | Author: Yotam <yotama9@gmail.com>
   | Date:   Sat Oct 17 23:19:14 2015 +0300
   | 
   |     removed swap fles
   |  
   * commit bb7121420ccbf7775b5ee752579ff7ecd67ed131
   | Author: Yotam <yotama9@gmail.com>
   | Date:   Sat Oct 17 23:15:14 2015 +0300
   | 
   |     Changed the channel scrapper to use cssselector
   |  
   * commit ab501663ed9e1f176ea7d1956727a495f252a8c4
     Author: Yotam <yotama9@gmail.com>
     Date:   Sat Oct 17 20:41:42 2015 +0300

         created
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing `git merge master` from within your branch, you are actually merging from `master` to `change_scrapper`, while I guess you'd like to do the opposite.
For you just branched from `master` and never fetched it, likely your branch is truly aligned with the main one (that is, already up-to-date).

Thus, once committed on your branch, checkout back to `master` and give from there `git merge change_scrapper`.